# Vim: search and replace a long string

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn server for superlists-staging.ottg.eu

[Service]
Restart=on-failure  
User=elspeth  
WorkingDirectory=/home/elspeth/sites/superlists-staging.ottg.eu/source  
ExecStart=/home/elspeth/sites/superlists-staging.ottg.eu/virtualenv  /bin/gunicorn \
--bind unix:/tmp/superlists-staging.ottg.eu.socket \
superlists.wsgi:application  

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to quickly replace "superlists-staging.ottg.eu" with "mysite.com" WITHOUT typing the entire string "superlists-staging.ottg.eu" (lets say there is a 200 character string the next time). I'm aware of:

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

but that would require typing the full string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

- you find a pattern for the text you want to change, E.g. `super.\{-}\.eu`

OR

- you move your cursor and yank the part you want to change (`f, t` may help you), then `:s/\V<c-r>"` will do literal match (`:h \V`) and paste the yanked text (`:h i_ctrl-r`)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know that `foo` is a regex, so you can just specify the string as you want it, e. g.

```
%s/superlists.\{-}\.eu/mysite.com/g
```

If you want to have it a bit more interactive, you can do the search first:

```
set incsearch
/superlists.\{-}\.eu/<ENTER>
%s//mysite.com/g
```

Or use a macro:

```
qq
/superlists
c/.eu/e<ENTER>mysite.com<ESC>
q
100@q
```

Comment: You mean with `.*`? Well it's a regular expression, so people need to know about them .....  In most cases, it's just faster to write. ... ok, I change it.

Comment: not only the greedy `.*`, also the macro.  in Op's example, not all `superlists ...` are needed to be replaced. your macro may remove more than expect. anyway, I believe you were showing the method, not the concrete codes. so it 's fine.